EFI Framebuffer in ubuntu 22.04
Ubuntu 20.04
I can see that in kernal log that EFI Frame buffer has been initiated successfully.
[    0.321440] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.321453] efifb: showing boot graphics
[    0.321858] efifb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, using 3072k, total 3072k
[    0.321859] efifb: mode is 1024x768x32, linelength=4096, pages=1
[    0.321859] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.321860] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0

And efi-framebuffer.0 is created in  sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer.
Ubuntu 22.04
I can see that in kernal log that EFI Frame buffer has been initiated successfully.
[    0.508054] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.508071] efifb: showing boot graphics
[    0.508870] efifb: framebuffer at 0xa0000000, using 8100k, total 8100k
[    0.508871] efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
[    0.508873] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.508873] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0

But efi-framebuffer.0 is not created in sys/bus/platform/drivers/efi-framebuffer,  but /dev/fb0 is present.
It indicates that the EFI framebuffer is likely being initialized, but the system is not naming it explicitly as efi-framebuffer.0. Instead, it's being registered under the more generic name of /dev/fb0 (EFI framebuffer is present but not explicitly named as efi-framebuffer.0)
In fwupd tool, as it reads height, width data from efi-framebuffer.0 when efi-framebuffer.0 is not explicitly created, tool can't read height and width.
Is this expected behaviour (efi-framebuffer.0 is not explicitly created).Could you please check and provide some advice on this.
Please refer: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/7598

Please check what?
